# Appending characters to strings in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This XML has details of the string to be appended, string length and character to append.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
    <input>
        <string>Auckland</string>
        <len>12</len>   
        <char>#</char>
    </input>

    <input>
        <string>Ohio</string>
        <len>3</len>    
        <char>*</char>
    </input>
 </data>
```

I also have an XSLT which should (ideally) use this logic:
while (length of string < specified length){
 concatenate(char, string)
}
else
{ truncate string to the specified length}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="append" match="/">
    <xsl:param name="char"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="string"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="len"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:value-of select="$string" />
    <html>
    <body>
    <xsl:for-each select="data/input">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(string) &lt; len" >
                <xsl:call-template name="append">
                    <xsl:with-param name="char" select="char" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat(char,string)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="len" select="len" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For some reason, the looping isn't working as expected. The loop executes once and displays the result.

For example, for the first XML input, the output should be ####Auckland, but the result is #Auckland. Can you help me identify the flaw in this code? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you pass a value in field parameter (`<xsl:param name="string"></xsl:param>`) but expect string parameter (`<xsl:param name="string"></xsl:param>`) so you never use what you passed.

Comment: That was a typo. Just corrected it. The o/p is as stated earlier #Auckland instead of ####Auckland

Comment: You need to use $len, not len, etc. But more basically, this doesn't have any chance of working. Everytime through the loop, you'll be generating another set of `html` and `body` tags. You need to separate the logic of handling the "/" case and doing your string padding.

Comment: @torazaburo: Thx. I'm new to this language, so could you please provide a bit more detail as to how I can incorporate the change?

Comment: In a statement such as `<xsl:when test="string-length(string) &lt; len">`, `len` refers to the child element named `len`; if you want to indicate the variable or parameter, you need `$len`. Note however that in `<xsl:param>` you do __not__ want or need the dollar sign in the value of the `name` attribute.

Comment: user2241388, You may be interested to look at an easy and simple, short and efficient, non-recursive solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried your XSLT, I didn't get any text output, mainly because in your code, your named **append** template expects parameters of **string** and **len** but you are calling it with parameters of **field** and **length** respectively. Additionally, your named template also matches the top-level document element, and as it stands it will output the **html** multiple times.

It is perfectly fine to have a matching template that is also a named template though. Try this XSLT instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data/input"/>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="input" name="append">
      <xsl:param name="char" select="char"/>
      <xsl:param name="string" select="string"/>
      <xsl:param name="length" select="number(len)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="string-length($string) &lt; $length">
            <xsl:call-template name="append">
               <xsl:with-param name="char" select="$char"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="string" select="concat($char,$string)"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <div>
               <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
            </div>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<html>
<body>
<div>####Auckland</div>
<div>Ohio</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the use of default values for the parameters. The first time the template is accessed, via a template match, the values will default to the values of the relevant elements. When you subsequently call it as a named template, it will used the values you pass it as parameters.

EDIT: Should you wish to truncate the values if they exceed the required length, simply replace the existing `<xsl:value-of select="$string"/>` with this line instead:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring($string, 1, $length)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. :)Now, I've understood how parameters are to be called and about matching and named templates.

Comment: I thing that the second `div` should contain `Ohi` - truncated to a length of 3, because that's the requested length in the input file. Easy fix in the XSL...

Answer (score 2):

**Here is an easy, efficient and non-recursive XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pFiller" select=
 "'$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$'"/>


   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data/input"/>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="input">
    <div>
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(string, substring(translate($pFiller,'$', char), 1, len))"/>
    </div>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<data>
    <input>
        <string>Auckland</string>
        <len>12</len>
        <char>#</char>
    </input>
    <input>
        <string>Ohio</string>
        <len>3</len>
        <char>*</char>
    </input>
</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>Auckland############</div>
      <div>Ohio***</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are specifying the use of XSLT 1.0; this would be a trivial one-liner in 2.0.
However, we can still do something simple if you are willing to make as assumption about the maximum length of the string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template name="append" match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="data/input">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(char,char,char,char,char,char,char,char,char,char,.), 10 + string-length() - len, len)"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you aren't happy with the assumption of a maximum length, you can always use the hack:

```
<xsl:variable name="char" select="char"/>
<xsl:variable name="chars">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[position() &lt;= $len]">
        <xsl:value-of select="$char"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Which works unless `len` is larger than the number of nodes in the input document. Then you can just do

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/input">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($chars,.), string-length(), len)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Bottom-line, although the recursive technique is frequently seen in XSLT 1.0, and is useful to learn, it is not really necessary in this particular case.